# How do I see what data AJAX is passing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to be able to see if the data that AJAX is passing is the correct data at the function `sendToServer`.

When the user submits the data that s/he wants, the submit function sends it to `next.php`. I want to see what `next.php` is receiving, how do I do this? It should be receiving the same as here:

```
$("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

So that I can insert the data into a MySQL database.

`next.php`:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['arr']));
foreach($data as $item){
   echo $item;
   // insert to db
}

?>
```

The code that I have so far is in the code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- #main {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    -->
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
    <div class="my-form">
      <!--            <form action="next.php" method="post">-->
      <button onclick="addAuthor()">Add Author</button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="addAuth"></div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
      <!--            </form>-->
    </div>

    <div id="result"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var authors = 0;

    function addAuthor() {
      authors++;
      var str = '<br/>' + '<div id="auth' + authors + '">' + '<input type="text" name="author" id="author' + authors + '" placeholder="Author Name:"/>' + '<br/>' + '<button onclick="addMore(\'auth' + authors + '\')" >Add Book</button>' + '</div>';
      $("#addAuth").append(str);
    }

    var count = 0;

    function addMore(id) {
      count++;
      var str =
        '<div id="bookDiv' + count + '">' + '<input class="' + id + '" type="text" name="book' + id + '" placeholder="Book Name"/>' + '<span onclick="removeDiv(\'bookDiv' + count + '\')">Remove</span>' + '</div>';
      $("#" + id).append(str);
    }

    function removeDiv(id) {
      $("#" + id).slideUp(function() {
        $("#" + id).remove();
      });
    }

    function submit() {
      var arr = [];
      for (i = 1; i <= authors; i++) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.name = $("#author" + i).val();
        obj.books = [];
        $(".auth" + i).each(function() {
          var data = $(this).val();
          obj.books.push(data);
        });
        arr.push(obj);
      }
      sendToServer(arr);
      $("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }

    function sendToServer(data) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          arr: JSON.stringify(data)
        },
        url: "next.php",
        success: function() {

        }
      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you ask for `echo($data)`? `print_r($data)`?

Comment: how do I see it in next.php

Comment: @learningbyexample Firebug: http://i.stack.imgur.com/03ONN.png and Chrome: https://vidyut.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/recover-comments.png

Comment: Another tool may help is wireshark.  If your ajax call isn't https, then you can see the exact data going to and coming back from the php next.js.

Answer (score 0):

Your js is sending a post request therefore you should receive the sent data just as you receive a normal html form post. 
try `var_dump($_POST);` to see under what index names are your data then you can use those index names to manipulate your data as you want.

Comment: Where do I put the var_dump() at? I want to see if the data is being passed

Comment: put it just after your opening php tag. and run that file.